# Copy time line markers to a new scene

Tags: animation

I am syncing an animation with a sound file and I used to mark key notes from the partition to drive actions in the animation.  I would like to save the time line with the markers to build a new animation using new objects based on the same partition and keep the time line and the markers as they are.  I could not find a way to do so?  Is it possible?  I tried to link or import the time line but could not find out how..

Comment: Finaly from a new blend file, cube deleted, I shift F1 to the original file that contains the scenes with the animation from where I want to get the time line.  I open in the file browser the blend file original, go to the scene folder and there is a object called the name of the original scene.  I import that object into my new blend file.  I can then use the elements from the old scene into in my new scene.  One can see on top of the 3D view in the scene menus, that I have now two scenes, the original and the new one.  I just can use or copy from the old scene into the new one the time line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timeline markers are part of the scene data, you will only get the markers if you import the scene into another blend file.

Blender can have [more than one scene](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/scenes.html#adding-a-scene) in the same blend file, you could create a full copy of the current scene, remove the items you don't want and start your new animation. Similarly you could save a copy of your file and remove the un-needed items in the new file.

The other option is to use python to export/import the markers.

Run this in your current file to export the markers -

```
import bpy

markerfile = '/tmp/markertransfer.txt'

with open(markerfile, 'w') as mf:
    for m in bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers:
        mf.write('{},{}\n'.format(m.frame, m.name))
```

Then in your new file run this to get matching markers -

```
import bpy

markerfile = '/tmp/markertransfer.txt'

with open(markerfile, 'r') as mf:
    for l in mf:
        f,n = l.split(',')
        bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers.new(n.strip(), frame=int(f))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I could not find out how to start a script doing just the import / export.  Thank you for your script that will help me get all the markers (287) into the new scene.  Great thinking.. Thanks again

Comment: To complete my comments, once one has imported the original scene into the new blender file, one gets two scenes, the imported one with it name, and the new scene that is named scene or whatever you named it. At that step, select the imported scene, then go to the time line and select with b box, all the markers.  Go to Marker menu where you have the options 'duplicate marker to scene ' or simply 'duplicate marker'.  Select the duplicate markers to scene and then you have a sub menu proposing either scene, the imported one or the new one.  Select the new one and that's it.